# ng2 table how to add links to the cells

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using ng2-table:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table

I want to be able to add links to some items for a certain column.
Here is my code, thanks.

```
res.content.forEach(item => {
              contentArray.push({
                age: 1,
                value: item.value,
                link: '<a href="' + 'http://google.com' + '">' + item.stored.substring(0,10) + '...' + '</a>' ,
              });
            });
            this.source.load(transactionContentArray);
```

This just puts the items in the table as a string like:

```
<a href="http://google.com">0000000000...</a>
```